# Routing in child component using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, core-ui

I’m using the CoreUI Pro template for a React dashboard, and trying to integrate logging in functionality into it. My log in is using AWS Cognito, so I’m using [this](https://serverless-stack.com) tutorial for that part.

The problem I have is that once logged in, the links don’t work.

My top level routes.js is below.

```
export default ({ childProps }) =>
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <AppliedRoute path='/' exact component={Login} props={childProps} />
      <UnauthenticatedRoute path='/login' exact component={Login} props={childProps} />
      <AuthenticatedRoute path='/dashboard' exact component={Full} props={childProps} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
```

In the Login component, I redirect to /dashboard and that works ok. Full is the name of the component which contains the dashboard.

Once the user is in the Full component, then I want them to be able to navigate around:

```
<Container fluid>
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/dashboard' name='Dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path='/deliveries/listDeliveries' name='List Deliveries' component={ListDeliveries} />
                <Route path='/shifts/listShifts' name='List Shifts' component={ListShifts} />
                <Route path='/locations/' name='Locations' component={Locations} />
                <Redirect from='/' to='/dashboard' />
              </Switch>
            </Container>
```

In the CoreUI template this works, but for me if I navigate to /locations after logging in, it goes to my 404 page. I thought about moving everything to the routes.js, but the problem there is that Full has a surrounding template for the page, it's just loading the components like Locations in one area of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nesting routes - see an example for reference [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy/nested-routes).

The issue is, that you have the **exact** attribute in your route to the `Full` component, so the component won't render when browsing to the `/locations` route. I suggest to restructure your routes, so that you can structure it like in the example above (e.g. `/dashboard/deliveries`).

Then you would leave out the **exact** attribute in the top level route and have routes like this in your `Full` component:

```
<Route 
  path={this.props.match.url + '/deliveries/listDeliveries'}
  name='List Deliveries'
  component={ListDeliveries}
/>
```

This would then match the route `/dashboard/deliveries/listDeliveries`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it